# Getting files from Sharepoint using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Good afternoon, I am using the Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM library to work with Sharepoint. I have a code where I get a list called MyDoc like this:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(url)
{
      varweb = context.Web;
      var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDocs");
}
```

Then I iterate through all the folders to find a folder with a suitable name and get files from there. With the help of `file.ServerRelativeUrl` I found out the link to the file on Sharepoint:

```
/MyDocs/Documents/Students/Homework/1lesson.pdf
```

How can I immediately access the `Homework` folder and download all the files from there without going through all the possible folders in the `MyDocs` sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the list, just use the method GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl within the context.Web object

```
var folder = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/MyList/MyFolder");
context.Load(folder);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```